# Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unexpected value [...] (options must start with a '--') && howTo? diff w/ properties file

Tags: liquibase

I'm trying to diff two databases from the command line in linux.  I'm hoping that someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong... my command is

```
./liquibase 
    --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver \ 
    --url=jdbc:mysql://{it'svalid}:3306/db_schema_1?useLegacyDateTimeCcxle=false&serverTimezone=UTC \
    --username={it'svalid}  \  
    --password={it'svalid} \
    diff \
    --referenceUrl=jdbc:mysql://{it'svalid}:3306/db_schema_2?useLegacyDateTimeCcxle=false&serverTimezone=UTC \    
    --referenceUsername={it'svalid} 
    --referencePassword={it'svalid} \    
    --changeLogFile=databaseChangeLog.sql
```

I'm getting this in response:

> java -cp
>   ".:/home/someguy/needit/liquibase/liquibase.jar:/home/someguy/needit/liquibase/lib/:/home/someguy/needit/liquibase/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/home/someguy/needit/liquibase/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/home/someguy/needit/liquibase/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/home/someguy/needit/liquibase/lib/logback-1.1.jar:/home/someguy/needit/liquibase/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/home/tkrueger/needit/liquibase/lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/home/someguy/needit/liquibase/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:/home/someguy/needit/liquibase/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/someguy/needit/liquibase/lib/snakeyaml-1.18.jar" liquibase.integration.commandline.Main
>   "--driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
>   --url=jdbc:mysql://{it'svalid}:3306/db_schema_1 --username={it'svalid} --password={it'svalid} diff --referenceUrl=jdbc:mysql://{it'svalid}:3306/db_schema_2 --referenceUsername={it'svalid} --referencePassword={it'svalid} --changeLogFile=databaseChangeLog.sql" Starting Liquibase at Thu, 02 May 2019 14:21:56 CDT (version 3.6.3 built at 2019-01-29 11:34:48) To
>   display the help, please pass the '--help' option on the command line.
>   Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unexpected value
>   '"--driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' (options must start with a '--')
>   liquibase.exception.CommandLineParsingException: Unexpected value
>   '"--driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' (options must start with a '--')
>       at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.parseOptions(Main.java:778)
>       at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:185)
>       at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:137)

I've dumped most of the parameters into a liquibase.properties file, to no avail... I thought I found someone else dealing with the leading doublequote on the rejected parameter string (i.e., it appears to be parsing the parameters as "-- instead of simply --), but I'm struggling to understand how to get around that while doing a diff, by putting all my parameters into a liquibase.properties file.

Comment: try to put `diff` at the end of the commands chain

Comment: I ended up abandoning my attempts to get it working in linux (for now) and got it kind of working in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You should check what end of line you have. I had same problem. Resolution was to change from windows eol to linux.