# LIQUIBASE - Cannot pass command with “-” sign in liquibase command line

Tags: command-line, liquibase

I’m new to liquibase, just started to research on it for 1 week, and i’m having an issue that really need you guys help

I’m trying to use command with “-” sign such as “rollback-count” or “update-to-tag” and I’m doing it in 2 ways:

- the first one is based on the official document, without the “–command” option:
  `liquibase --changelog-file=mychangelog.sql rollback-count 1`
  → It throws error: **Unexpected value ‘rollback-count’, options must start with a '–'**
- the second one is with the “–command” option:
  `liquibase --changelog-file=mychangelog.sql --command=rollback-count 1`
  → It throws error: **Unexpected value ‘1’, options must start with a '–'**

here is my command line, and the actual error message
[image]

no matter what i do, i still cannot get the command line to run. but if i dont use command with “-” sign, it works fine, such as “update” or “rollback tag1.1”

Is anybody know how to fix this problem?

thank you very much

Comment: if you run the same from Powershell, does it work? (if you can try it out). Try without the --command= (just liquibase --changelog-file=mychangelog.sql rollback-count 1)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before here [Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unexpected value [...] (options must start with a '--') && howTo? diff w/ properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55960342/unexpected-error-running-liquibase-unexpected-value-options-must-start-w)

The answer to that question was to change the end of line command. One suggestion was to use `diff` at the end of the line, the other was to try changing the end of line from Windows to Linux.

Comment: i still got the same error though :(

Comment: @MinhTran did you try the other responses shared above? There's one from Eduard and one from Yeshwant. Please let us know if you get a different outcome when you do.

Answer (score 0):

the command i use for rollback by count for windows

`liquibase --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --classpath="mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar" --changeLogFile=changelog-master.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liquibase" --username=root --password=root rollbackCount 1`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).