# gradle and luiquibase run diffchangelog task from command line with arguments

Tags: gradle, liquibase

I would like to execute a gradle luqibase plugin `diffChangelog` task with my custom arguments from command line.

I **DO NOT want to add/modify any of the project files**, no modifications of build.gradle, no gradle.properties or such i just want to run a task and pass its parameters from command line and i am so far unable to do so i would like to distribute my script that executes this task in one bash file.

I have a problem even figuring out how to pass parameters to a gradle task, moreover even the format of the arguments is confusing - there are documentation snippets pointing that i should use camelCase or hyphenated version also zero/one/two hyphens are possible in the beginning . Additionally can either use -P or -D to pass arguments to gradle so far none of it seem to work it looks like the arguments are not being passed at all.

I would like to execute something like:

`./gradlew diffChangelog --url=AA --username=BB --password=CC --reference-username=DD --reference-password=EE --reference-url=FF --changelog-gile=GG`

Of course proper values will be provided by inline.

Is there a concise way to do so? So far googling up for the solution results in multiple complex explanations requiring modification of existing files and then passing arguments, is there really no way of just running a gradle task with arguments or am i missing something?

Update:
The error i am alyways getting is:

`liquibase.exception.CommandValidationException: Invalid argument '--reference-url': missing required argument`

Comment: The Invalid Argument error can indicate something's off in the syntax, sometimes it's because a word being used is reserved by the database and so it can't be used in the liquibase command without causing issues.  This documentation has been helpful for some with this error: https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/working-with-command-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

You should check what end of line you have. This can sometimes be resolved by changing the end of line from from windows eol to linux.

Reference:
[Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unexpected value [...] (options must start with a '--') && howTo? diff w/ properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55960342/unexpected-error-running-liquibase-unexpected-value-options-must-start-w)